# DFS Traversal object to Dictionary casting error

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, depth-first-search

```
public void NestedDictIteration(Dictionary<string,object> nestedDict)
{
    foreach (string key in nestedDict.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        object nextLevel = nestedDict[key];
        if(nextLevel == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)nextLevel);
    }
}
```

I keep getting an invalid casting error on the recursive call on the last statement. This is the error that I see: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'." What is the best way to solve this? I was not able to call .ToDictionary on nextLevel.

Comment: What are you storing as values in the dictionary? You seem to assume the `object` value is a `Dictionary<string, object>`, but in fact it is a `string`.

Comment: The dictionary represents a deserialized JSON that I am trying to traverse through recursively, so the value types do change, the string represents the field name and the object represents the value or the nested object that I would need to traverse through.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already expecting that some of your dictionaries or nested ones will not have a value of type `Dictionary<string,object>` otherwise your code will get into an infinite loop, so you should not guarantee that all your dictionaries' values are of type `Dictionary<string,object>`. Therefore you have to not continue recursion in case you face a dictionary with a value not of that type:

```
public void NestedDictIteration(Dictionary<string,object> nestedDict)
{
    foreach (string key in nestedDict.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        var nextLevel = nestedDict[key];
        if(nextLevel == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else (nextLevel is Dictionary<string, object>)
        {
            NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)nextLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)nextLevel);
```

This line fails because the value in `nextLevel` is not a `Dictionary<string,object>`, but instead a `string`. You mention that the string is a JSON object representing a dictionary, but a direct cast only works if the object you cast is of the given type, or convertible to the given type (it is possible to cast an `int` to a `double` for instance).

In this case, having the data stored as a JSON string, you need to deserialize the data into a `Dictionary<string,object>` before recursing. How this deserialization is done depends on the format of the data in the JSON object, but the code could look something like this:

```
public void NestedDictIteration(Dictionary<string,object> nestedDict)
{
    foreach (string key in nestedDict.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        object nextLevel = nestedDict[key];
        if(nextLevel == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var nextDictionary = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(nextLevel);
        NestedDictIteration((Dictionary<string, object>)nextLevel);
    }
}
```

You can look at the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library for deserializing JSON objects.